# Is 「でいい」 the same as 「でもいい」?

Tags: particle-で, particle-でも

For example in the sentence:

> 書くだけ**でいい**ですか.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant for the example sentence to be: 書くだけでいいですか. Without the mo. So the question is basically, is でいい the same as でもいい.

Comment: でいい means just that (それでいい?), でもいい implies asking for permission for sth. that may be troublesome. (You are aware of the side effects? それでもいい?)

書くだけでいいですか -> All I need to do is to write (eg sth. down)
書くだけでもいいですか -> All I want to do is to write, may I?

Comment: What is wrong with this question? (why is it downvoted?)

Comment: I would like to know that too... please explain why the downvote, it is pointless downvoting without further details.

Answer (score 20):

The meanings are quite similar, but there's a subtle difference.

Both phrases involve settling for something, or one person making a choice on behalf of another: `お昼ごはんはハンバーガーでいい？` "Would a hamburger do for lunch?" Or something is sufficient: `そこにおくだけでいいです` "Please just put it there [and I'll do the rest.]"

But `でもいい` has an added sense that there is something better or preferable out there, but you are settling, or asking, for something less. This comes from the use of `でも`, which has a negative conjunction.

That is, `お昼ごはんはハンバーガーでもいい?` has a nuance of, "I know you like something else," or perhaps, "I don't know if you like a hamburger or not." Another example would be: `名前を書くだけでもいいですか？` and this would mean something like, "[You want to me to put down my address for this petition, but] would it be OK if I just write my name?"

Comment: Intonation/emphasis also has an effect here, right?

Comment: I corrected the spelling, grammar, and punctuation, which I think should be uncontroversial. Additionally, I couldn't help but also change the formatting a little, mainly highlighting the Japanese text. Only because otherwise there was so much punctuation it was a little hard to read. I hope that's acceptable.

Comment: So the も makes it _"Would a hamburger do for lunch **as well**?"_ _(or "**also**")_?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, but I would just like to add a sidenote to the existing answer by Kawaguchi-san

There is a site that I use for my studies now, and recently I found a very helpful [article there on the difference between でいい and がいい](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/japanese-particle-de.html)

I just thought that this might be a good addition/expansion on the topic

P.S. Also, to understand the nuance, I personally find it helpful to translate も in でもいい as ”even", e.g. これだけで**も**いいですか？ ＞ Is it OK **even** if I do just this?

Though, if you draw a parallel with the 'usual' function of も in general and, especially, も/は for amounts (e.g. 百人もいました > There were as many as a hundred people), then a 'more universal' translation would be "**as much/as many as**", so the example about would translate as "Is it OK if I do just as much as this?"

Interesting, I have not thought about it before I started writing this