# The meaning of "ありちゅーかありじゃないですか"?

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm going through some comments on an old blog and came across this dictation of an interview that's gotten me a bit befuddled. The seiyuu's asking the writer about what will happen to the seiyuu's character in the following year.

> 声優さん「婿でもいいです、この際」
>
> 作家さん「それでもありちゅーかありじゃないですか？ …どうしようか…」

The writer's wording confused me tbh, so randomly guessing I think it's something like:

> Seiyuu: At this rate, he could even become a groom.
>
> Writer: That's possible as well, isn't it? What to do do...

If anyone could confirm/correct me with an explanation of what 'ありちゅーかありじゃないですか？' means I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- それでもあり: that'll be fine too
- ちゅーか: contracted ていうか, which is a colloquial expression meaning "or rather".
- あり: fine
- じゃないですか?: isn't it?

Saying それでも implies there is other ideal options, and 婿 is not the best (See this [answer about でいい and でもいい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12485/5010)).

作家さん first said それでもあり, implying 婿 is a possible alternative which may be selected reluctantly. Then he rethought it and repeated ありじゃないですか without それでも, indicating 婿 may be a really good option.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed and helpful reply!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes people shorten 「ていうか」with 「ちゅうーか」, your translation looks pretty correct to me :).